# Asus laptop Win10: Are there protocols that show when the computer went to Sleep?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, logging, asus

According to my default settings, it goes into Sleep Mode after 30 minutes of inactivity when plugged in, and 15 minutes when on battery.

However, on rare occasions, it doesn't go to Sleep and still stays on for unclear reasons;
also, auto-updates that restart the computer can have such an effect sometimes.

So my question is: Is there a way for me to look at some log/protocol that shows at what time the computer went into Sleep mode? I.e. to ensure that it did go to Sleep after the 30 minutes, while I wasn't in the room?

This is mainly privacy related in this case, since my laptop requires a password each time it's turned on after being in Sleep - and if I leave the room for 1 hour, leaving it on, and then it happens NOT to go to Sleep, and sb enters it after 50 minutes, they'd have access to my device.

A log telling me it did go to Sleep after those 30min, or didn't, respectively, would be very useful for such instances (2nd best thing after remembering to turn it off myself, of course).

Comment: The Windows log is the Event Viewer.

Comment: All you have in Windows is a command that will indicate what blocked you from going into Sleep mode.  As for the protocol it's called ACPI

Comment: I'll go look at that Event Viewer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks - what command is it specifically? (And to clarify, I meant "protocol" in the common sense, which I think is called "log" in computer terms - while protocol means sth else, software-related. Is that ACPI a protocol in the latter sense i.e. doesn't show the events that happened previously? That's prb that Event Viewer then, right?)

Comment: In a Command Prompt type `powercfg /?` see `powercfg /requests`, `powercfg /systemsleepstudy` etc. Also there is a power troubleshooter in *Settings - Troubleshoot - Additional Troubleshooters - Power*. Programs such as Media Players ask windows not to sleep while they are doing stuff but are supposed to tell windows when the video finishes. They call `SetThreadExecutionState` to tell windows they need to stay awake or that the need has passed.

Comment: Try a clean boot. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and on the Options menu tick Hide Windows Entries. Untick what is left. Keep a note of what you are doing. Also run it as admin.